# How to customise slider thumb's shape with CSS and Webkit?

Tags: css, graphics, frontend, slider, webkit

I know how to customise some properties of a slider's thumb with CSS and Webkit.
E.g.:

```
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #0ac2ac;
    background: #0ac2ac;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor: grabbing;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Instead, I do not know and failed to find on the Web how to **customise a slider thumb's shape by using CSS and Webkit**.

**I wish to use a polygonal shape instead of the slider thumb's default round shape.**

Is there a way to do that by using CSS and Webkit? If not, what is the most efficient alternative solution for achieving my purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer yet? I've got the same task. Make it rectangular :D Silly bosses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `clip-path: polygon(<path>)` and changing `background: <colour>` to `background: url("<entire svg code>")` to the style shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I run into same task recently, I am using somewhat similar css as the question posted,and also stuck on the same issue.

In my case, it seems that I have to add margin-top to let it work.

I added:

```
margin-top:-8px
```

If I don't add it, it will always be the blue circle.

Comment: That sounds odd to me. Perhaps you could share code with snippets to help reproducing the issue.